# Is the inner product of a vector space a Hermitian function?

Tags: definition, inner-products

In my textbook **Analysis I** by Amann/Escher, there is Remark 3.7 about inner product space as follows:

> [image]

From this Wikipedia's [page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hermitian_function), the definition of Hermitian function is given as:

> [image]

---

We have $\overline{(x|y)} = (y|x)$ and $(y|x)$ is not necessarily equal to $(-x|-y)$. As such, I think the inner product is **not** necessarily Hermitian w.r.t Wikipedia's definition.

Could you please confirm whether my understanding is correct or not?

Comment: The book's definition of the term "Hermitian" might not match the Wiki page's definition.